# Student registration form

Tags: html, css, html5, form

> ## Problem statement
>
> Create one form having registration and student login fields for course using HTML5 elements and CSS3 styling.
>
> ## Expected Output
>
> ### [image]

## Solution

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .div{
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #2A646C;
            width: 60%;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .form{
            background-color: #C4D8E2;
            height: 350px;
            width: 50%;
            margin: auto;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .para1{
            height:20px;
            color: #5D8AA8;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        .para2{
            width:50%;
        }
        .para3{
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
        .span1{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: "Times New Roman";
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #5D8AA8;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
        .span2{
            color: #5072A7;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: "Times New Roman";
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .span3, .span4{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: "Times New Roman";
            font-size: 14px;
            color: white;
        }
        .span3{
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
        .span4{
            color: white;
            font-style: underline;
            font-size: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            bottom: 20px;
        }
        .register{
            margin: 5px;
            width: 50%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .login{
            margin: 5px;
            width: 40%;
            height: 230px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 80px;
            background-color: #5072A7;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }
        .submitbutton{
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 20%;
            height: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 70px;
        }
        .loginbutton{
            border: 1px solid orange;
            background-color: #5072A7;
            width: 20%;
            height: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            bottom: 40px;
        }
        .checkbox{
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
```

---

```
            <div class="div"></div><br><br>
    <form class="form" method="POST" action="javascript:void(0)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h3>Enter the system</h3>
        <p class="para1"><span>It is necessary to login in Your account in order to sign up for a course.</span></p>
        <p class="para2"><span class="span1">ARE YOU NEW?</span><span class="span2">REGISTER</span></p>

        <div class="register">
            <input type="text" name="username" required placeholder="User name" autocompleter="off"
                            pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9._-]{6,10}$" size="40" maxlength="10">
            <br><br>
            <input type="email" name="emailid" required placeholder="Email" autocompleter="off"
                                pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9 _.-]+@[A-Za-z.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{3,4}$" size="40" maxlength="30">
            <br><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" required placeholder="Password" autocompleter="off"
                                pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9 _.-]{8,15}$" size="40" maxlength="15">
            <br><br>
            <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" required placeholder="Confirm Password" 
                                pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9 _.-]{8,15}$" size="40" maxlength="15" autocompleter="off">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" class="submitbutton">
        </div>
        <div class="login">
            <p class="para3"><span class="span3">ALREADY A STUDENT?</span><span class="span4">LOGIN</span></p>
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="loginname" required placeholder="User name" autocompleter="off"
                            pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9._-]{6,10}$" size="40" maxlength="10">
            <br><br>
            <input type="password" name="loginpassword" required placeholder="Password" autocompleter="off"
                                pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9 _.-]{8,15}$" size="40" maxlength="15">
            <br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="yes"><span class="checkbox">Remember me?</span>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Login" class="loginbutton">
            <span class="span4">Forgot Password?</span>
        </div>

    </form>
```

---

1) How do you review the usage of `position` attribute? Can it be avoided for `login` div container, `register` button and `loginbutton`?

2) Can we improvise this code to be responsive?

3) Can the regex pattern be improved?

Comment: you shouldn't need anything absolute here, and for responsive just add a media query breakpoint `@media (min-width: 768px){}` and make the containers block instead of inline

Comment: Strange problem statement: "Create _one_ form". I see two independent (and mutually exclusive) forms in that screenshot. I also see some odd text/poor UI ("Remember me?" with a question mark, "Your" capitalized). Oh and the "Register" button doesn't line up with the fields above it... Mostly, though, the task is more about CSS than HTML5 it seems. Sure, HTML5 tags are useful for _behavior_ (i.e. email-type fields), but matching the screenshot is a pure layout task regardless of HTML-flavor. In all, a pretty poor problem statement. Where the heck did this come from?

Comment: @Flambino From [here](https://github.com/shamhub/FrontEndDev/blob/master/acadgild/syllabus/session8_assignments/ACD_FEB_Session_8_Assignment_1_Main.pdf). Would you please suggest the recommended layout, without any hesitation in ignoring minor/major errors in problem statement.

Comment: @overexchange Oh, the layout is fine. It just struck me as odd that the problem statement specifically mentioned HTML5, but said nothing of CSS, though that's the bigger task here. CSS is about layout and styling, so a visual reference makes sense for that. But HTML is about structure and semantics, yet the exercise doesn't give you anything to check your work against. It's as though a writing teacher told you "Write a novel in English. I don't care what it's about or if it's any good, but the finished book should look exactly like this." That wouldn't be a useful _writing_ exercise.

Comment: @Flambino We know, what technologiess we want for required layout, given. So, getting into the correctness of problem statement, is unnecessary. Expected layout speaks a lot more than the problem statement.

Comment: @overexchange I disagree. There are many, many ways to write the HTML and still achieve that layout. I could do the same exercise with really, really bad HTML, and still make it look exactly like that screenshot. I could do it all with a `<table>` like it's 1999, or simply  misuse HTML elements all over the place. Or have great HTML but really poor CSS. And it'd _still_ end up looking like the screenshot. None of this is a criticism of your code; it's a criticism of the exercise.

Comment: @Flambino This exercise is mainly using html5 & css3. Question edited

Comment: @overexchange And I've read the original problem statement you linked to. It doesn't mention CSS, even though it's certainly necessary to complete the task. So again, I just consider this a poor exercise. Still, any exercise is good exercise, but all I'm saying is that I hope you find better learning materials later on.

Answer (score 4):

#### Styling and readability

You are using classes as id's, both by not using a class twice or more and by naming them after the specific element you are using the class for.

You do not use css-selectors to their full extent. You can select elements that appear as children of an other element for example, and you can select elements based on (part) of the value of an attribute. Consider using `input[type=checkbox] span` instead of `.checkbox` for example. Another part is that you do not select groups of elements based on what you want them to be. Want elements in the right box to have white text? Do not set the text color for each <s>id</s>class that appears in there, but select `#login` and set the text color there.

The headers appear with different sizes, and one of the elements with class `span4` appears below the form through the other element with class `span4`. You should make the layout consistent.

#### Validation, semantics and correctness

You should validate your code on [the site of w3](https://validator.w3.org).

Validation shows that you use an attribute `autocompleter` for your input elements. This is a non-existing attribute. You likely meant to use `autocomplete` (without an 'r').

You use the `pattern` attribute without the `title` attribute. When the user enters an invalid value, it is not made clear to the user how to improve this. Add a `title` attribute to tell what input is expected.

Your login button and register button both have the name "register".

You can use a `<label>` element to better specify that the text in that element explains what a checkbox is for. Either make the checkbox input element a child of the label, or use the `for` attribute of the label to link the checkbox and label. In either case this has the added benefit that you can check and uncheck the checkbox by clicking the label.

You are using one form. This means that all input fields in that form that are marked as `required` must be filled in. Except that this means that you have to fill in both the registration part **and** the login part to be able to pass the form.

#### Responsiveness and use of position

There are various ways of making two boxes appear next to each other. Other ways of accomplishing this is by using `float`, or preferably flex boxes. The latter one will make it easier to create a responsive layout that displays well on other screen sizes.

Your over-usage of ids-disguised-as-classes might make it difficult to create a responsive layout, as you are thinking of elements as individual components, rather than of elements in relation to each other and what certain group of elements have in common. Since you have control over both the html and the css, there is no real reason why you shouldn't be able to create a responsive layout using `@media` queries. See [mdn for more information about usage of flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Comment: What about `action="javascript:void(0)"`? Is it the right usage?

Comment: You'll likely replace that at some point with the uri of the actual script that handles the input. Even if you use javascript to login using ajax, you still want to have an actual script uri in there in case javascript is turned off.

Comment: I modified the code accordingly [here](https://github.com/shamhub/FrontEndDev/blob/master/acadgild/assignments/session8/assignment1/file.html) but the height of the `container2` does not grow accordingly

Comment: This is not the place to get help on how to fix that. I do not see a `@media` query though. See http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html for more information too.